# Multiple domains and organic groups in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, multiple-domains, organic-groups, drupal-domain-access

I want to setup one main site and four sub sites that share the same Drupal install. This is because the client has asked to have users that can edit all the sites from one CMS frontend and does not want to keep logging into separate drupal sites.

Also the sites need to share some content between each other so it makes even more sense to try and create the five sites using one Drupal install.

I've been looking at Organic Groups and it looks like it will do what I want.

What I've not been able to work out is how I can essentially point 4 domains to the same Drupal install and for it to return the specific organic group homepage.

Does anyone know how this can be done using Organic Groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, from what you are describing, it sounds like the [domain access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module might be a better fit.

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database. The module allows you to share users, content, and configurations across a group of sites.

Check out this case study from Row Eleven Wine Co. on their use of the module: http://drupal.org/node/369398.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) and [Organic groups domain support](http://drupal.org/project/og_domain) modules. There doesn't seem to be Drupal 7 support for the second one, though. Domain Access is what you'd use to setup multiple domains on a single Drupal install, at least.

Answer (score 0):

You actually should use both.  This response is probably too late but if you use Domain Access it will get the domains to work properly but if you want to have users capable of editing content across all "groups" then you don't really need organic groups (OG).  But lets say you want to have Frank be the editor of Frank's Group but not Sarah's group, you could use OG and OG Roles to specify that Frank can edit his group and his group alone, while Sarah can edit her group and her group alone.